# Version property missing when converting Domain to JSON

Tags: json, groovy, jackson, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

In GORM-standalone I have a simple domain class like:

```
@JsonIgnore( [ 'owner' ] )
class Person implements MongoEntity<Person>{
  String id
  String name
  String owner

  Long version // attempt to hack
}
```

When an instance of Person is converted to JSON, the `version` is not output to resulting JSON string.

Any way to get it done automatically?

P.S.
Even adding `version` prop expicitly does NOT add it to resulting JSON...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the configuration property in `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`

```
grails.converters.domain.include.version = true
```

or in  `grails-app/conf/application.yml`

```
grails:
  converters:
    domain:
      include:
        version: true
```

Comment: I'm not using Grails, only GORM-SA